# Different behavior between a click Selenium and Mouse click

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-firefoxdriver

**Current Behavior**

Using this piece of code

```
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
    from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    browser = webdriver.Firefox()
    button_value = '/html/body/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div/form/div/div[3]/div[3]/a[2]'
    .........
    browser.find_element(By.XPATH, pin_box).send_keys(pin)
    browser.find_element(By.XPATH,, button_value).click() #Click NEXT Button
```

on this page

[image]

I end up going back to the login [page](https://www.mymanulife.com.hk)

Whereas if I put a break point on

```
browser.find_element(button_type, button_value).click()
```

and I click with the mouse manually 
[image]

I am going to the desired page

**Expected Behavior**

To end up on the desired page (i.e not the login page) via Selenium like if I was manually clicking on the next button

PS:  PIN [html source](http://www.mediafire.com/file/8b4dzun57uam2kg/Welcome_-_Manulife_Customer_Web_Site.7z/file) in case you need

Comment: What are you exactly clicking here `browser.find_element(button_type, button_value).click()`. What values are passed?

Comment: I am clicking Next button, let me amend sample code)

Comment: what is the locator for Next button you have used?

Comment: By.XPATH, I have amended the code few minutes ago along with Jonah comments

Comment: @JBRolland : Post the html of the next button so that OP can assist you.

Comment: Your question should remain strictly a question; I rolled mack your latest edit. If you want to post an answer of your own with a solution, you are welcome to do that. Then please mark one of the answers as accepted, to signal that your problem was solved.

Comment: alright @triplee, done and thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to click with `webdriver wait` or with send `ENTER` key on `next` button. As last option you can try to click with Javascript .

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[.='NEXT']")))
element.click()
```

**try click using `Enter` or `Return`**

```
element.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

**OR**

```
element.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

**OR (try to click with Java script but without wait as it can be fail on wait)**

```
element=browser.find_element(By.XPATH, "//a[.='NEXT']")
browser.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
```

Comment: Thanks. It ended up that later in my code there was a redirection of the URL. This redirection did not give the time to the submission to be completed. The follow code `WebDriverWait(browser, self.timeout).until(EC.invisibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//a[.='NEXT']")))` fixed the issue. Thanks for your help

Comment: May I know how did you find the Xpath `"//a[.='NEXT']"` whereas when I am copying the Xpath from the inspector I got `/html/body/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div/form/div/div[3]/div[3]/a[2]`?

Comment: @JBRolland This xpath is searching element based on text. Which xpath you are mentioning is absolute and not reliable. Any changes in html structure can break it.

Comment: @JBRolland  Yes with webdriver wait it get time to load element in DOM. Please accept it as answer if it solve your problem.

Comment: Yes exactly and this why I was asking, I did not know such search function exist. Thanks again

Comment: @JBRolland  Your question is about to find NEXT BUTTON element and click for which my solution works. You never mentioned redirection and wait for to load next page. So i have provided the solution as per your question. So you should accept it as answer. For new problem you can check exist question on stack overflow or raise a new question.

Comment: my question was about to end up on the proper page (expected behavior). I put your answer as accepted (main thing for me is my issue is now solved)

Answer (score 0):

Later in my code there was a redirection of the URL. This redirection did not give the time to the click submission to be completed. The follow code fixed the issue

```
.......    
browser.find_element(By.XPATH, pin_box).click() #Click NEXT Button
WebDriverWait(browser, timeout).until(EC.invisibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, pin_box)))
```

Sorry and thanks for those who helped me on this

Comment: Your question is about to click on Next button not about to wait to load for next page after click. You should have mentioned it in question.